# TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/ error when trying to login admin panel in django site

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a django application smartDNA/core. When trying to login to admin site, its not bringing admin login page. Its giving me error like:

**TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/**

'adminmedia' is not a valid tag library: Template library adminmedia not found, tried django.templatetags.adminmedia,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.adminmedia,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.adminmedia

codes that I used
urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include('smartDNA.core.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),

    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
    }),
)
```

admin.py

```
    from core.models import Verification

class VerificationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display   = ('asset_code', 'scan_time','credential','status','operator','location','auth_code')
    list_filter    = ('status','operator','location')
    ordering       = ('-scan_time',)
    search_fields  = ('asset_code',)

admin.site.register(Verification,VerificationAdmin)
```

core/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from core import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',

 url(r'^login$',views.login,name='login'),
   url(r'^fetch$',views.fetch,name='fetch'),
   url(r'^register$',views.register,name='register'),

   #   url(r'^upload$',views.upload,name='upload'),
   #   url(r'^verify$',views.verify,name='verify'),

)
```

Any idea why is this happening,,,,,?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This template tag is deprecated since `Django 1.5`.

> > The template tags library adminmedia, which only contained the deprecated template tag {% admin_media_prefix %}, was removed. Attempting to load it with {% load adminmedia %} will fail. If your templates still contain that line you must remove it.

Reference: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#miscellaneous)

You should use `django.contrib.staticfiles` app, its documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: can you it more clear, from where and what I should remove. And what I should include.